# ImportError: No module named PySide

Tags: python, pyside

I have installed PySide in my Ubuntu 12.04. When I try to use import PySide in the python console I am getting the following error.

```
import PySide
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PySide
```

My Python Path is :

```
print sys.path ['', '/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
```

how to fix this problem ?

Comment: How did you install Pyside  How have you tried to fix your own problem?

Comment: I followed steps specified here [http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Linux]

Comment: I think i found the issue, I installed python3-pyside but I am using python2.7. After removing python3-pyside I installed  python-pyside, which is working fine.

Answer (score 5):

To use python 3, just follow the instructions here:

https://wiki.qt.io/PySide_Binaries_Linux

which in ubuntu 12.04 means just typing one line in the console:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyside
```

Answer (score 2):

Now, the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'` - issue can be solved for `python` versions > 3.4x with `pip install pyside<most-recent-version>` (currently [version 6](https://pypi.org/project/PySide6/) in April 2023) like so:

```
~$ pip install pyside2
Collecting pyside2
  Downloading PySide2-5.15.2-5.15.2-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38.cp39-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (164.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 164.3 MB 2.4 kB/s 
Collecting shiboken2==5.15.2
  Downloading shiboken2-5.15.2-5.15.2-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38.cp39-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (956 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 956 kB 2.7 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: shiboken2, pyside2
Successfully installed pyside2-5.15.2 shiboken2-5.15.2
```

When I resolved the issue for myself, the most recent version was `pyside2`.

To me the error occurred when trying to start the `jupyter qtconsole` from terminal:

```
~$ jupyter qtconsole
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/bin/jupyter-qtconsole", line 5, in <module>
    from qtconsole.qtconsoleapp import main
  File "/home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qtconsole/qtconsoleapp.py", line 60, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
  File "/home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

Then, I initially tried to install the ancient `pyside` in my current `Python 3.9.0` - environment, which led to the following error:

```
~$ pip install pyside
Collecting pyside
  Downloading PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz (9.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 9.3 MB 389 kB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/bin/python3.9 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kbfhpmbj/pyside_d579850ca35442f99958b51deaf6e16b/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kbfhpmbj/pyside_d579850ca35442f99958b51deaf6e16b/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-07ab3csm                      
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-kbfhpmbj/pyside_d579850ca35442f99958b51deaf6e16b/        
    Complete output (1 lines):                                                          
    only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]  
    ----------------------------------------                                            
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

The solution to it was, as mentioned above in the beginning, installing `pyside2` instead of `pyside`:

```
pip install pyside2
```

---

**EDIT:**
Note that the most recent version of pyside can vary, currently in April 2023 it is [version 6](https://pypi.org/project/PySide6/).

Comment: Maybe now the command should be `pip install pyside6`

Comment: Hi @XuMuK, thanks for the hint, just edited the text.

Answer (score 1):

The latest build and install instructions for PySide are here:

http://pyside.readthedocs.org/en/latest/building/linux.html

Comment: but they refer only to python 2.7, while (at least in theory) PySide should work with Python 3.2

Comment: instructions work for all python versions (from 2.7 to 3.4) just replace 2.7 with 3.2 or whatever version of python you are using.